Create a stacked bar chart in Plotly where each stack is ordered with the largest bar at the bottom of each stack
I'm plotting the following chart, but I would like to sort each stack separately so that the largest bar is at the bottom of each stack and smallest at the top.
Unsorted stacked bar chart
I used the following code to generate it:
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name=0)

# Filter and aggregate data
resources_to_plot = ['Elec (Grid)','Heat (Dom)', 'Heat (Com)','Heat (Ind - LT)', 'Heat (Ind)']
df_filtered = df[(df['Scenario'] == 'Case1c') & (df['Resource'].isin(resources_to_plot)) & (df['Prod_Con_GWh_per_Yr'] > 0)]
aggregated_data = df_filtered.groupby(['Resource','Technology'])['Prod_Con_GWh_per_Yr'].sum().unstack()

# Reorder elements in the x-axis
ordered_resources = ['Elec (Grid)', 'Heat (Dom)', 'Heat (Com)', 'Heat (Ind - LT)', 'Heat (Ind)']
aggregated_data = aggregated_data.reindex(ordered_resources)

# Plotting the stacked bar chart
fig = px.bar(aggregated_data.reset_index(), x='Resource', y=aggregated_data.columns[1:],
             title='Title',
             labels={'value': 'Prod_Con_GWh_per_Yr', 'variable': 'Technology'},
             barmode='stack')


I tried .sort_values(by=...) but I don't know how to make it sort each row individually. I also tried looking for an argument of px.bar that could do this but there doesn't appear to be one.

We can sort the values in each row and then plot the chart. Like here:
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# Read in the data (replace this with your actual file path)
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name=0)

# Filter and aggregate data
resources_to_plot = ['Elec (Grid)', 'Heat (Dom)', 'Heat (Com)', 'Heat (Ind - LT)', 'Heat (Ind)']
df_filtered = df[(df['Scenario'] == 'Case1c') & (df['Resource'].isin(resources_to_plot)) & (df['Prod_Con_GWh_per_Yr'] > 0)]
aggregated_data = df_filtered.groupby(['Resource', 'Technology'])['Prod_Con_GWh_per_Yr'].sum().unstack()

# Reorder elements in the x-axis
ordered_resources = ['Elec (Grid)', 'Heat (Dom)', 'Heat (Com)', 'Heat (Ind - LT)', 'Heat (Ind)']
aggregated_data = aggregated_data.reindex(ordered_resources)

# Sort each row of the DataFrame so the largest values are at the bottom of each stack
aggregated_data = aggregated_data.apply(lambda row: row.sort_values(ascending=False), axis=1)

# Plotting the stacked bar chart
fig = px.bar(aggregated_data.reset_index(), x='Resource', y=aggregated_data.columns,
             title='Title',
             labels={'value': 'Prod_Con_GWh_per_Yr', 'variable': 'Technology'},
             barmode='stack')

# Show the plot
fig.show()

The line aggregated_data = aggregated_data.apply(lambda row: row.sort_values(ascending=False), axis=1) sorts the values in each row in descending order.
px.bar creates the stacked bar chart (barmode='stack').
Since the data is expected to be in long format, we reset the index of aggregated_data
